# Ubuntu web server not accessible from public network

Tags: networking, ubuntu, iptables

I have a machine running Ubuntu Server 18.04.02 LTS and have lighttpd installed, running on port 80.

When I connect to the machine using port 80 from another computer within the local network, I can see the web interface of lighttpd.
However, when I try to connect to the external IP-address of the machine running lighttpd (and after properly port forwarding in the router), the machine doesn't reply to any connections.

Here is a tcpdump of a local connection (working properly):

```
19:32:44.738145 IP sitecom.router.64601 > homeserver.http: Flags [S], seq 4216620690, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
19:32:44.738207 IP homeserver.http > sitecom.router.64601: Flags [S.], seq 102829168, ack 4216620691, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

Now here is a tcpdump of a remote connection (not working):

```
19:33:20.001892 IP google-proxy-66-249-81-103.google.com.61995 > homeserver.http: Flags [S], seq 3678483043, win 62920, options [mss 1430,sackOK,TS val 1150615851 ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0
19:33:21.000315 IP google-proxy-66-249-81-103.google.com.61995 > homeserver.http: Flags [S], seq 3678483043, win 62920, options [mss 1430,sackOK,TS val 1150616851 ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0
19:33:21.017192 IP google-proxy-66-249-81-103.google.com.39536 > homeserver.http: Flags [S], seq 144332281, win 62920, options [mss 1430,sackOK,TS val 1150616868 ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0
19:33:22.017517 IP google-proxy-66-249-81-103.google.com.39536 > homeserver.http: Flags [S], seq 144332281, win 62920, options [mss 1430,sackOK,TS val 1150617868 ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0
19:33:22.999945 IP google-proxy-66-249-81-103.google.com.61995 > homeserver.http: Flags [S], seq 3678483043, win 62920, options [mss 1430,sackOK,TS val 1150618851 ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0
19:33:24.018853 IP google-proxy-66-249-81-103.google.com.39536 > homeserver.http: Flags [S], seq 144332281, win 62920, options [mss 1430,sackOK,TS val 1150619868 ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0
19:33:25.043043 IP [MY-EXTERNAL-IP].38736 > homeserver.http: Flags [S], seq 3115771267, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 24063591 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
19:33:26.052905 IP [MY-EXTERNAL-IP].38736 > homeserver.http: Flags [S], seq 3115771267, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 24063841 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
19:33:27.000064 IP google-proxy-66-249-81-103.google.com.61995 > homeserver.http: Flags [S], seq 3678483043, win 62920, options [mss 1430,sackOK,TS val 1150622851 ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0
19:33:28.017512 IP google-proxy-66-249-81-103.google.com.39536 > homeserver.http: Flags [S], seq 144332281, win 62920, options [mss 1430,sackOK,TS val 1150623868 ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0
19:33:28.092087 IP [MY-EXTERNAL-IP].38736 > homeserver.http: Flags [S], seq 3115771267, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 24064342 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

I've tried clearing the iptables using "iptables -F" and disabling the firewall using "ufw disable" but nothing seems to have any effect.

Does anyone know what could be going wrong here?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

The command `route -n` results in the following output:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.57.10.5      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0
10.57.10.1      10.57.10.5      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.57.10.5      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
[SOME-EXTERNAL-IP]    192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp2s0
128.0.0.0       10.57.10.5      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-79cc7                                                  752b6ff
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp2s0
192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 enp2s0
```

Comment: Can the server find a way out? What does `route -n` say? Can homeserver `ping 1.1.1.1`?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks for your reply. The server can ping 1.1.1.1 just fine.
See my updated question for the result of `route -n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit of this issue, thanks to @HagenvonEitzen.

After I ran `route -n`, I found out that there was a tunnel called tun0. Since I had no use for this tunnel, I decided to remove the tunnel using `ip link set dev tun0 down`.
I think I might've accidentally created this tunnel when playing with OpenVPN.

After this, the tunnel was gone from the `route -n` output and I was able to access the web-server just fine from outside of my local network.

Thanks again!